# Left-ratio and right-ratio in (not necessarily commutative) field

Tags: projective-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, quantum-mechanics, noncommutative-geometry

I am reading Birkhoff–Neumann (1936) about (not necessarily commutative) field $F$.

The authors use terms right-ratio and left-ratio in [section 13](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968621?seq=11).

Right-ratio is denoted as $[x_1, x_2, ... x_n]_r\,$  $x_i \in F$ where not all elements $x_i=0$. Similary left-ratio is $[y_1, y_2, ... y_n]_l$.

Two right-ratios $[x_1, ... x_n]_r\, ,[\xi_1, ... \xi_n]_r\,$  are "equal" iff $\exists z\in F:\xi_i=x_iz,\ i=1, ... n$

But in [section 14](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968621?seq=13), they also use term ennuples: not right or left ratios. We can define vector-operations and inner-product for ennuples.

I don't understand to this term (ennuples) in not commutative field and their connection to ratios. Any example (of left/right-ratios with ennuples) will be helpful.

- Birkhoff, Garrett; von Neumann, John
  “The logic of quantum mechanics.”
  Annals of Mathemathics (2nd series) **37** (1936), no. 4, 823–843.
  MR[1503312](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1503312)
  JFM[62.1061.04](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:62.1061.04)
  DOI:[10.2307/1968621](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1968621)

Comment: If you are going to talk about a paper, you should tell us what the title of the paper is.

Comment: The logic of quantum mechanics - Birkhoff and von Neumann (page 833 and 835)

Comment: I believe this is a question about the two definitions of projective space over a division ring. "Ratios" are called "homogeneous coordinates", and "ennuple" is now written as $n$-tuple.

Answer (score 1):

An "ennuple" just sounds like an element of $F^n$, and "right-ratio" just sounds like an equivalence class of ennuples under the equivalence relation $x\sim y$ iff $\exists z\in F^\ast$ such that $xz=y$. (Here I'm using the $^\ast$ to denote the nonzero elements of the ring $F$).

If we're talking about a division ring $D$, then an ennuple $x\in D^n$ would be equivalent to the members of the set of ennuples $xD^\ast$, and so together they all form a single right-ratio.

For commutative fields, both of these things would just boil down to the same thing: the subspace spanned by $x$. But in general I guess there is no guarantee they are the same subspace.

<s>The "ratio" aspect probably is a reference to the following example. If you think about pairs of nonzero integers (from $\Bbb Z^\ast$), then you can have ennuples with $n=2$: $\Bbb Z^\ast\times\Bbb Z^\ast$, and their left/right ratios would be a model of $\Bbb Q^\ast$. (For example, $2(1,2)=(2,4)$ evidences that $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$ as ratios.</s> Actually I suddenly realized that the relation in this case would not be symmetric! But I still think it gives a little idea of the distinction between the ennuples and equivalence classes.

Comment: What mean exactly "star" ($F^*$)?

Comment: I'm using it to mean "nonzero elements of". I'll add a note about that...

Comment: Another common explanation is "slope", the ratio of $\Delta y$ to $\Delta x$ can usually be written as a fraction $\Delta Y / \Delta X$, but if $\Delta X = 0$ we run into trouble, and so write $[ \Delta X : \Delta Y ]$ instead, understanding that $[1:2]=[2:4]=[3:6]$ etc. When you use more coordinates, you are finding the slopes of planes, hyperplanes, etc.

Comment: @lada: ennuples contain quaternions, “ratios” are one-dimensional subspaces of quaternions. For instance, if $n=3$, then “ennuple” is normally written as “triple”, and the triple $(1,i,j)$ has left ratio $\mathbb{H}(1,i,j) = \{ (h,hi,hj) : h \in \mathbb{H} \}$ and right ratio $(1,i,j)\mathbb{H} = \{(h,ih,jh) : h \in \mathbb{H} \}$. The left ratio contains $(i,-1,k)$ but not $(i,-1,-k)$, and the right ratio contains $(i,-1,-k)$ but not $(i,1,k)$.

Comment: @lada No, that doesn't sound right... take a look at $x=(1,i)\in \Bbb H^2$. The coset $x\Bbb H^\ast$ collectively represents the right-ratio. The left ratio is $\Bbb H^\ast x$. But look: the two sets are not the same. You can work out that $\alpha x =x\beta$ iff $\alpha=\beta$ and $\alpha$ commutes with $i$. So, for example, $xj$ is not in $\Bbb H^\ast x$.

Comment: rschwieb and Jack Schmidt : Thank you